# How can i get data in android HTML 5 mobile app from mysql server

Tags: php, android, html

It is possible to run PHP code in Android emulator? If possible how I can get data from MySQL to Android emulator?

Comment: Such an ugly, bad ideal... What are you using to build your HTML5 apps?

Answer (score 3):

Using **WebService** you can get data from server to your android emulator or device or send data to server from emulator or device.

Answer (score 1):

No . only Java language is allowed for android SDK .in case you cant use java , write backend stuffs in JavaScript .

Comment: could have any example code in javascript to connect and fetch data to mysql server from html5